# Is there a StackExchange-like voting plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

The [Vote it up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/) plugin is nice but once you vote something you can't undo.

Is there a voting plugin which is similar to the one you find here at StackExchange?

(You can undo your vote and vote down).

Comment: See if any of the similar topics yield any useful information or links to plugins that suit: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=thumbs+up+down - Just a suggestion because we've had a handful of questions similar to this.

Comment: There was a plugin I ran across about a year ago that did this. I can't remember the name. If I find it, I'll post it as an answer for you.

Comment: I can't post an answer to this but another one that looks similar to Q&A WordPress plugin by WPMUdev is Design Wall Question & Answer -https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-question-answer/

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is a Stackexchange-like voting plugin for WordPress.  The beta was just released today developed by [one of our members](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu) and available from [WPMUdev](http://wpmudev.org).  The plugin is [Q&A WordPress Questions and Answers](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin).

See screenshots below:

[image]

&

[image]

Comment: I originally upvoted this answer, but having actually *used* WP Q&A (and having paid for it even)... It sucks. As an admin it is a nightmare. There are no good moderation/curation features. People try and treat it like a forum and there is no way to make an "answer" that is really a question into it's own question. There's a reason it took Jeff & Co. 6 months to get the beta out the door. This plugin is rudimentary at best. I do *not* recommend it. You're better off just getting a PHPBB forums...

Comment: I never have used it and was not endorsing it anyway.  Thanks for the comment, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Check out [CubePoints](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cubepoints/).

Is a point management system designed for WordPress blogs.
Users can earn points by posting comments creating posts, or even by logging in on your site. Also your users can be awarded with ranks automatically when they reach certain points as well.

Comment: That's pretty kool!

Comment: @kaiser Yes, it's a very nice plugin, and in the 3beta version includes a paypal module and some other features also!

Comment: This is not a voting plugin. It is a point management plugin.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces The reason of your downvote? do you think that isn't a voting plugin? I suggest you to take a beep look on how it works and free your imagination on how to use it!

Comment: @Philip, I read cubepoints code source. Why not to create  its own voting system if you need to create a whole module for that in Cubepoints. I think already built in modules of Cubepoints allow only points and achievements management, not a stack-exchange-like voting system.

Comment: @Philip And this is exactly  what you said in your answer, which is not corresponding to the aim of the current post (SE-like- voting system).

Comment: @Philip SE reputation points are not money, they are mean to learn and share constructive knowledge. At least I downvote when I have a starting discussion comment. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90970/jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-when-the-page-is-accessed-as-a-wordpress-template-pag/90973#90973

Comment: I know that SE reputation points are not money (for this reason i help here). Don't be mad with me, i just asked the reason to comment and downvote a 2+ years old answer! It will be nice to see you help someone in the future with your answers. All the best!

Comment: what about cubepoints and SE-like voting system?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [GD Star Rating](http://www.gdstarrating.com/); it's similar to Vote It Up. It allows you to add thumbs up/down and/or star ratings to posts, pages, comments, etc.

Its major drawback is the complex setup and options.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, There is a Wordpress voting plugin. Please Visit http://plugins.ohiowebtech.com/downloads/wordpress-voting-photo-contest-plugin/ for details