# jQuery Ajax() doesn't work when the page is accessed as a WordPress template page

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-template

In one file (test_ajax.php) I have a which on change loads another page (registration_form_race_type.php) with a short message via jQuery Ajax(). It works fine when "test_ajax.php" is accessed via its absolute URL which is :

```
http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/wp-content/themes/test_ajax/test_ajax.php
```

But amazingly enough, the Ajax functionality ceases to work if the exact same page "test_ajax.php" is accessed via its WordPress address which is :

```
http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/?page_id=13
```

I insist these both URLs point to the same two PHP files.

Here is the code of "test_ajax.php" :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Test Ajax 01
*/
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {    
            jQuery('#event_id_from_list').change(function() {       
                var event = jQuery("#event_id_from_list").val(); 
                var data = "event_id=" + event;         
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'registration_form_race_type.php', 
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){ 
                        jQuery('#div_race_type').html(data); 
                    }
                });         
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class='required' type="text" name="event_id_from_list" id="event_id_from_list" />
        <option value='Paris'>Paris</option>
        <option value='London'>London</option>
        <option value='Rome'>Rome</option>
    </select>   
    <div id='div_race_type' class='section'>            
        <?php require_once('registration_form_race_type.php'); ?>           
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

And the code of the page called via Ajax, "registration_form_race_type.php" :

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['event_id'])) echo 'you selected '.$_GET['event_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Please follow [these steps](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins) to use AJAX.

Comment: @toscho: thanks, I read this but is it not for plugins only (since some steps involve adding stuff in plugin file)?

Comment: Your AJAX callback function can load any file from any theme or plugin. But the **URL** should be the one WordPress offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice to use the wp built-in ajax. it allows avoiding many problems and brings many benefits.

an example that I wrote to illustrate the 2 approches:

[Dynamically changing navigation links (next and previous) via AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89808/dynamically-changing-navigation-links-next-and-previous-via-ajax)

I am here to provide with explanations

good luck

Comment: Thanks. I think the WordPress way of doing Ajax is awfully complicated (I mean compare to jQuery: load(page.php), done! For WordPress you need to follow tutorials..